# Higher Order Component (HOC) and window resize listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, event-listener, window-resize

I have the following HOC and I thought about creating 3 states where these would be my breakpoints

- mobile
- tablet
- desktop

But I'm wondering how I could set these states to true when a breakpoint is reached example:

- mobile: less than 767
- tablet: between 768 and 991
- desktop: between 992 and 1919
- large screens: 1919 and 2520

and then when one of these breakpoins was reached the state would change to true

Also how I could do to pass only one state (whichever is true) at the moment in my HOC?

Can I improve this logic?

```
import React from "react";

const withWindowResize = Component => {
  class WrappedComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        mobile: false,
        desktop: false,
        tablet: false
      };
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeUpdate);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.update();
    }

    resizeUpdate = () => {
      this.setState({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
      });
    };

    render() {
      return <Component />;
    }
  }
  return WrappedComponent;
};

export default withWindowResize;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do it, but following your approach, you could do something like the following, where you just have a `size` variable on your state changing based on the specs you provided above.

In that way, you just have to pass `this.state.size` to your component.

```js
import React from "react";

const withWindowResize = Component => {
  class WrappedComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        size: this.findSize()
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeUpdate.bind(this)); // initialize your listener
    }

    componentWillUnmount() { // remove event listener on component unmount
      window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resizeUpdate.bind(this));
    }

    findSize() {
      return window.innerWidth > 1919
          ? "large"
          : window.innerWidth > 992
          ? "desktop"
          : window.innerWidth > 768
          ? "tablet"
          : "mobile"; // find currentSize
    }

    resizeUpdate() {
      const currentSize = this.findSize();

      this.setState({
        size: currentSize
      });
    }

    render() {
      return <Component size={this.state.size} />;
    }
  }

  return WrappedComponent;
};

export default withWindowResize;
```

Notice I'm using `React.PureComponent` as **we don't want to change our state and re-render our `Component` on every window resize.**

This will be the same as using `React.Component` and checking right before the use of `this.setState`, if our currentSize is different from the one we have on state, before updating it.

```js
if (currentSize !== this.state.size) {
  this.setState({
    size: currentSize
  });
}
```

Comment: I used this for some reason my app says that it is not possible to read props

i think i have some problem in emu app.



function App () {
  console.log (this.props)
  return (
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default withWindow (App);

Comment: Do I think it is better to create a context?

Comment: if you are using a `function` for your `App` and not a class, then you can't access props from `this`, as `this` is a reference to the `window` and not your component. Try `function App (props) { console.log(props) return <div></div> } export default withWindowResize(App);`

Comment: Okay thank you very much, is there a clearer option for doing this?

Or do you think this is a good option?

Comment: I think this approach fits your case best

Comment: I just had a small problem the size the first time the browser opens starts with null

Comment: I have updated my answer, finding the first correct value of size from right into the constructor by calling `this.findSize`, also used by `resizeUpdate` later to find `currentSize`